# Does protobuf-net allow backward compability when a type has moved assemblies or namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net, backwards-compatibility

I'm currently having a hard time moving DTOs from one assembly and namespace to another assembly and namespace. This is because I am using binary serialization to send/receive data. In binary serialization the contract is basically the assembly name and type namespace + name. If you move a type to a different assembly you essentially break the contract.

Does protobuf-net behave in the same way? What is the foundation of the protobuf-net contract? Does probuf-net allow me to move a type from one assembly to another without breaking backwards compatibility? What about moving namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version of this is "yes, that will be fine - and to work just like that is one of the main reasons I wrote it in the first place".

> In binary serialization the contract is basically the assembly name and type namespace + name.

That depends on how you define "binary serialization"; if you mean "serialization to something that happens to be binary, i.e. non-text", then that is unrelated. If you mean "type-based serialization", then: indeed - this is a major pain point.

> Does protobuf-net behave in the same way?

No, it does not.

> What is the foundation of the protobuf-net contract?

Types are not described at all; the caller supplies the type of the outermost member, and all other types are implied by the type's layout.

Members are identified solely via numeric keys; **if** those keys exist on both sides (and they don't necessarily need to : you can add / remove members), then they must be compatible. For example, these are compatible:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo { // in namespace X
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
...
[ProtoContract]
public class User { // in namespace Y
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

If you serialize a `Foo` and then deserialize it as a `User`, the data from field 2 is pushed into `UserName` (the data from field 1 is ignored by default, but can be stored if you need that). This, however, is ***not*** with `Foo`:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class BadClass {
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public double Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

(this will fail, as the wire-types for `string` and `double` are not remotely comparable)

> Does probuf-net allow me to move a type from one assembly to another without breaking backwards compatibility? What about moving namespaces?

Yes to both. When you consider that you can be serializing in C# and deserializing in a Java or C++ model, it *has* to work this way.

Comment: "If you serialize a Foo and then deserialize it as a User" does this mean I have to specify what type I want it to Deserialize to every time? I want deserialization to automatically detect what class to deserialize to based on what it was serialized as (using some contract). If protobuf can do that, then how does it know that "Foo" is now "User"? If it can't do that, is there a way to get that same kind of behavior?

Comment: @Mark yes, you need to tell it the root type. This is the same in most contract-based serializers - you need to do this for XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, Json.NET etc. For the very reason that it is pure data: it doesn't have an explicit CLI type.